# 77 unsigned long const warnings when compiling in Debug (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, warnings, constants

Just wondering whether anyone knows why I would be getting 1 warning in Debug (iPhone Simulator) and 77 warnings in Debug (iPhone Device) when building my application!?

Is there something I can modify in my project settings other than "Symbols Hidden by Default" (since that didn't work) to remove these warnings from the build? I miss the green Build Successful bar.

```
ld: warning: unsigned long const& std::min<unsigned long>(unsigned long const&, unsigned long const&)has different visibility (default) in /Users/fulvio/Projects/zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/build/Debug-iphoneos/libZXingWidget.a(QRCodeReader-C190599C861BFE46.o) and (hidden) in /Users/fulvio/Projects/MyApp/build/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ScanViewController.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this relates to the second half of your question)

i recommend:

```
GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN = NO
GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = NO
```

you'll want identical settings for every target/object/configuration. just understand what these switches do before applying them, since you may introduce bugs by changing these settings. using standard c++ techniques, it's easy to develop a library that is safe using these switches. (ref: ODR)

Answer (score 1):

as to why you may have different warnings: the functions may be truly inlined for one architecture, and the function copy may not be emitted.

Answer (score -1):

You could fix the problem the warnings are pointing out, that should do it.

Comment: You should strive for a clean compile.  You shouldn't try to sweep 77 warnings under the rug.